# How can I quickly defrost the water line in my refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator

Every 12 months or so, the water line in my refrigerator ices up, so it won't serve water (the ice maker still works fine). Working the ice out of the line has historically (two or three times in the past four years) been a long process: because I don't know where the ice plug is under the surface of the door, I hit the entire door with a hairdryer for about 30 to 60 minutes and attempt to blow air with an electric pump through the line. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Does your fridge have a light in the ice/water dispenser?  I've found that leaving that turned on overnight often is enough to unfreeze my line when plugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of Googling, I found [this post](http://bustedrefrigerator.com/is-your-refrigerator-water-dispenser-line-frozen), which recommends the [IceSurrender Frozen Water Line Tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DJFFT62) (4.8 stars from 300+ reviews!). It's a thin tube attached to a syringe that allows you to squirt hot water directly on the ice plug, no matter where it is in the door.

---

Update: It arrived today, and it enabled me to defrost the water line after three or four iterations of inserting the tube and squirting water --- five minutes worth of work, rather than a tedious half hour with the hair drier. I'm very happy to have this my toolbox for the next time the water line freezes up.

Comment: What kind of fridge is this ?

Comment: If your water dispenser freezes, then it needs removed so you can re position or replace the thermal cover that protects it

Comment: I understand this is a common problem for GE side-by-side fridge/freezers (see the post linked in the answer).